# Getting access denied with an AWS hosted file on S3 from an AWS tutorial

Tags: amazon-s3

I am trying to download a file hosted on S3 and I am getting access denied errors. I was wondering if it was an issue on the AWS side or something on my side.
In the tutorial site below it has a link to download  LoadingDataSampleFiles.zip            https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/tutorial-loading-data-download-files.html

I click the link and get an access denied page.

I find that AWS has incomplete info on some of there tutorials which can be very aggravating when trying to learn!!!

Comment: It is on the AWS side, I'm having the same issue.

Comment: Others have confirmed this as well.     

Same issue with this file from another tutorial.  GRRRrrrrr!
s3://awssampledbuswest2/tickit/allusers_pipe.txt

From this tutorial - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/gsg/rs-gsg-create-sample-db.html

Comment: AWS has fixed the issue, the zip is now downloadable.